# Homestead & Vagrant Sporadically Timing Out On Windows 10

Tags: vagrant, homestead, vagrant-windows

I'm trying to get a Homestead box up and running on windows 10. I've followed all the steps, configured my Homestead.yaml correctly, and then ran *'vagrant up'*. Everything booted up correctly (with no errors), and I was able to access the index file that I have in my public directory via the hostname I set up for the site. Everything worked perfectly, and I thought I was in the clear. Until I tried to set up Laravel.

I ran *'vagrant halt'* to shut the box down, deleted the folder I had mapped with my test file in it, and ran *'vagrant new mysite'*. This recreated the same folder I was using before, with the same public directory inside that I was mapping to, and of course additionally all the Laravel files. What happened then when I tried to access the page is a timeout.

I then tried to SSH into the box (this had worked before and I was able to see the same files I had mapped), and was greeted with a timeout.

Here's what I've found out since:

I don't believe it is related to the laravel install itself, because even if I clear out the laravel index.php file (or add just an echo) I still get a timeout.

No amount of vagrant halt, vagrant provision, or vagrant up seems to solve the issue

The only way I've been able to get it working again is to reboot my host computer, start the box again, and then I seem to be able to access the site once or twice, before it starts timing out again for no apparent reason.

I've read and tried a few tips online to no avail:

Make sure virtualization is enabled in your bios - it is.

Try the newest test build of virtualbox (to fix windows 10 compatibility issues) - the same thing happens with both VB 5.0.10 and 5.0.13

Delete all host-only networks in Virtualbox network preferences - I did this and the connections were recreated next time I ran vagrant up, but to no avail

Windows firewall and antivirus software are disabled.

This is extremely frustrating becuase I am on a deadline and there's little helpful information out there regarding this problem. Has anyone experienced this and found a solution? Help greatly appreciated. Here's my Homestead.yaml file for reference, if it helps:

http://pastebin.com/BxgZY7F8 (had to use pastebin, Stack O messes up the formatting)

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution to this that worked for me:

I ran vagrant halt.
I downloaded the patch from here - https://www.virtualbox.org/attachment/ticket/14040/VBox-Win10-fix-14040.exe
I ran the patch as an Administrator, and kept it running
I ran vagrant up
I closed the patch

This resolved all timeout issues, and on subsequent 'vagrant up's I did not need to have the patch running in the background.